# Inline SVG breaks in Safari and Mobile Safari

Tags: css, svg, safari, cross-browser, mobile-safari

I recently launched a site which used a bit of inline SVG.

```
<svg class="divider-icon" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 55.221 58.079" enable-background="new 0 0 55.221 58.079" xml:space="preserve" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">
     <path d="[...]"/>
</svg>
```

Everything was perfect in Chrome and Firefox, but when I tested on an iPhone or in desktop Safari, the layout was completely broken and many of the SVGs were missing. I ran the source through the W3C validator and everything was find. I work with SVG a lot, so this was very confusing...

Answer (score 19):

It turns out that Safari and Mobile Safari freak out if you omit the `height` and `width` attributes I was setting the dimensions with CSS, which worked fine in other browsers. But I had to add those attributes back in to make it behave consistently:

```
<svg class="divider-icon" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     width="55.221px" height="58.079px" viewBox="0 0 55.221 58.079" enable-background="new 0 0 55.221 58.079" xml:space="preserve" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">
     <path d="[...]"/>
</svg>
```

Notice the `width` and `height` attributes that were missing above.

Also, it's interesting to point out that the value of `preserveAspectRatio` matters. I had a couple other inline SVG elements that had `preserveAspectRatio="none meet"` and they were unaffected by this issue.

Comment: I was having problems in IE9 until I added the width/height attributes as well. Thanks

Comment: I encountered the same problem today, and this suggestion helped. SVGs with just the "viewBox" value worked fine on multiple Windows desktop browsers, but the images wouldn't show up in iOS 14.8 (iPhone 13) browsers (Chrome and Firefox) without including the "width" and "height" properties. Also, since my original images didn't have the "preserveAspectRatio" property, and they started working fine is iOS, I just continued without that property. I'm not sure it's necessary.

Comment: I had a similar problem where the inline svg simply did not show up in Safari on an iPad (though working on firefox/chrome on linux/android). It was sufficient to apply a `width` and `height` CSS rule to the `svg` element to get it rendered. It was not necessary to add `width` and `height` attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Another scenario / fix for this is if you're scaling your SVG via CSS, to make sure that you have both `max-width` and `max-height` declared.

```css
.whatever svg {
  vertical-align: middle;
  max-height: 1rem;
  max-width: 1rem;
}
```